# How can i create .bat file to run "devenv" command with VS2012 Developer Command Prompt?

Tags: c#, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

i want to run this code to rebuild my project every X minutes

> devenv /rebuild Debug "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myProject\Project.sln"

Now i can run this command only in Developer Command Prompt for VS2012,
my question is, can i create .bat file to run this through Developer command prompt,
if yes, what is the code lines that i need to write in .bat file?

Answer (score 2):

There is a batch file called: **vsVars32.bat**.

Call that from your .bat file and it will setup the environment.

(Note there are other 'flavors' of the file, I think that is the correct one).

Comment: Ok, i'm calling it with "START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"" and then what? how can i  give it my command line to rebuild the project?

Comment: Put: Call  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"  as the first line in your batch file.

Comment: And then in the same line i add the command? like this : Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" devenv /rebuild Debug C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myProject\myProject.sln

Comment: I believe that is correct.   Note:  When I've setup batch files to do builds, all the settings are in the solution and project files.  I've only used the supplied batch file when doing C++ builds...years ago.  BTW, there is another file called VsDevCmd.bat discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774375/difference-between-vsdevcmd-bat-vcvarsall-bat-in-vs2012